# Including timestamp in output from "RAISE" in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

When I put this in my-script.sql :

```
RAISE INFO 'Hello, world!';
```

and run the script with psql, I get :

```
psql:whole path/my-script.sql:282: INFO:  Hello, world!
```

How can I replace `psql:whole path/my-script.sql:282:` with time of execution ?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I wanted to replace the text at the left of `INFO:` with something I defined. Seems it's not possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `now()`

```
RAISE INFO '% Hello World!', now();
```

The result will be

```
INFO:  2020-04-20 21:01:43.080733+00 Hello World!
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, Sorry for not being clear, I wanted to replace the text at the left of `INFO:`